# Create horizontally scrolling div of divs

Tags: javascript, html, css

What I need, is a bar with a fixed width and height, that is filled with `div`s and will scroll horizontally. My original problem was that elements wouldn't stay at the top. I fixed this by adding `display: inline-block`. But as you can see from the example below, `div`s will be added below the other `div`s instead of next to them when it overflows the container, even with `top: 0px;`.

```js
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  const e = document.createElement("div");
  e.className = "d2";
  d1.appendChild(e);
}
```

```css
#d1 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  outline: 1px solid #000000;
  overflow-x: auto;
  /*overflow-y: hidden;*/
}

.d2 {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  top: 0px;
  background-color: #454545;
}
```

```html
<div id="d1"></div>
```

But it starts scrolling vertically instead of horizontally. How can I force elements to be positioned at the top of the container at all times?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it. You will have to increase `#d1` height for the scrollbar

```css
#d1 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  outline: 1px solid #000000;
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  display: flex;
}

.d2 {
  width: 30px;
  min-width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #454545;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Either set your container element to `display: flex; flex-direction: row;` or set the children to `display: inline-block;`

Comment: This has introduced a new problem, I have edited my answer.